# Artifactory UI monitoring service status showing "online (0 of 0 nodes)" after migrating JFrog platform to new virtual machine

Tags: artifactory

I have an existing JFrog/Artifactory Pro 7.27.10 RPM-based install (on a CentOS 8 VM) that I recently migrated to a new (Centos Stream 8 VM) running JFrog/Artifactory Pro 7.31.13 (also installed via RPM).

After copying my existing `master.key` file from the original JFrog install to the relevant directory, I started up the Artficatory Pro service on the new VM and proceeded to migrate my data using the "Simple migration with downtime" process described in [this JFrog whitepaper](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-for-artifactory-backups-and-disaster-recovery/).  Everything worked fine, Artifactory is running as expected on the new VM and all my data appears good.  I moved my frontend proxy DNS aliases over to the new VM and shut down the proxy on the old VM.

One problem I am now noticing is that in the Artifactory admin UI, the **Monitoring** > **Service Status** now doesn't appear to report my Artifactory/JFrog platform microservice status any more.  It does show Artifactory with the correct backend IP address (running on port 8082) but then the "Status" shows "Online" with (0 of 0 nodes) and the ">" fold down arrow shows nothing when clicked.  I went back to my old Artifactory instance and checked and it was still showing the single node with all of the individual JFrog platform service statuses properly.

My guess is that I missed something in the migration process and/or something else needs to be configured to allow the services to show up on the monitoring page, however I'm at a loss as to what this is or even where to look for it.  I looked through the `system.full-template.yaml` but nothing seems obvious there.  And while the Artifactory docs are usually fairly comprehensive, the [page about monitoring](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Monitoring+Service+Statuses) doesn't seem to give much insight about how this is configured or what to do if it's missing.  Also not sure if the initial startup of Artifactory on the new VM *before* I migrated by data affected how the monitoring was configured such that it now doesn't work with the imported data (unfortunately I didn't check the monitoring UI in the new VM before I did the data migration so I can't say for sure if it was initially working)

A couple of other details which may be relevant:

- when migrating my VM, I kept the same (FQDN) hostname, but the IP address was different
- I used the same frontend (nginx) proxy configurations on both the old/new VMs though I'm not sure if this is relevant here or not.
- With the exception of going from CentOS 8 to Stream 8, the VM configurations themselves should be nearly identical as I create them from a kickstart (which was only updated for the new stream repo paths).  Again not sure whether this is relevant at all here.

Any ideas on where I should be looking to figure out how to fix this?

Comment: The first thing is you kind of tried to do an upgrade in this migration which is not recommended. If you are migrating to a new VM or new environment, make sure each and every resource versions are the same, and then you can upgrade it. For me, it seems more like a front-end issue. Try running this curl http://localhost:8046/router/api/v1/system/health command on the VM and see f all services are healthy

Comment: @MuhammedKashif thanks, I ran the curl and it is showing 7 services, all in healthy state.

Comment: Good, then the issue seems to be related to the different frontend versions from 7.27 to 7.31. As this is kind of upgrade you performed, I believe this is the issue here. You can also check the browser console for any errors.